# How to keep backward compatibility of the dynamic library embed C(.so file) between different Python versions

Tags: python, c, embed, compatibility

My program needs to import xxx.so, and this xxx.so file is compiled under Python2.4.

I want to run my program under Python2.7 & Python2.4, but there is an error when import xxx.so under Python2.7, I know that is due to mismatching with the Python version.

My question: **should I compile xxx.so file to match each Python version?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C extension modules are version specific. Each different version of Python requires a different version of the extension module. You need to compile the extension module from source linking against the headers and libraries for the target Python version.

Comment: What's the normal sulotion to solve this issue? Include all the xxx.so files and use sys.version to decide to import corresponding one?

Comment: The normal solutions are to either build from source, or supply different binary install packages for different python versions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should compile it with the matching Python version **using the same compiler** to assure ABI compatibility.

It's not a problem on *nix platforms, where compiler is bundled with the operating system, but may give you headaches on Windows, where many different compilers are used (mingw, visual studio, etc).

Python C API documentation describes compilers used by the official builds.